# Predicting which products a customer wants to buy

Tags: c#, neural-network, prediction

In a project I have, I want to be able to select a range of products that a customer might want to buy. The range of products should be selected based on patterns of other customers.

I am currently thinking about neural networks, however I am not sure if that is the way to go. Since I am learning about this, I am looking for good examples/tutorials to help me on this.
So far, I was thinking that multi-layer feed-forward neural network would do the trick, but usually the articles are talking about one predicted value, while I am looking for a range of values. The idea that I got is to use the error to calculate the range. Is that the way it is done?

My other approach is more statistical by using probability.

Can anyone point me to the right direction, preferably with C# examples as it is the chosen language to work with?

Comment: The question is to general - you didn't do anything yet and you ask for examples. It's called "shopping cart" problem, there are plenty of articles about it. Go, read, implement, and when you'll have problems with it - ask.

Comment: Sorry if it is too general. I am looking for a direction, because I got stuck. Asking questions is not about being specific. Sharing a problem with others can help in getting several solutions to a problem. Have you questioned the fact that I cannot be more specific?

Comment: If you can't, then it's not the right place for your question. Asking on SO requires you to be speciffic. "Where to start?" questions are too broad. You cannot ask about algorhitm and implementation at the same time, you need to do some deeper research first. Then consider looking for help at http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't point you at any tutorials. However, I used to work on the peripherals of this area alongside people who were very experienced in this sort of thing and their opinion was, overwhelmingly, that a probability-based approach is the more cost-effective of the two.

Machine learning of one kind or another is undoubtedly the more powerful technique but it requires a colossal amount of comparative time and effort, and the quality of the results may not prove to be worth the additional resources.